# How do i make this code reusable?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my application, i have a check, which checks the COUNT of a bunch of database tables. If each of these COUNTS is above a certain threshold, then it sets a property as active. Here is an example of a controller where a user adds room information

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,RoomTypeID,Description")] Room room, int propertyId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            room.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            room.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            room.PropertyID = propertyId;
            db.Rooms.Add(room);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            var roomCount = db.Rooms.Where(r => r.PropertyID == propertyId).Count();
            var rateCount = db.Rates.Where(r => r.PropertyID == propertyId).Count();
            var imageCount = db.PropertyImage.Where(r => r.PropertyID == propertyId).Count();
            if(roomCount >= 3 && rateCount >= 3 && imageCount >= 3)
            {
                //Set Property as ACTIVE
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The problem i have, is that i want to run this check (the 3 database COUNTS and the 'if' statement) on a whole bunch of controllers. I don't want to have to duplicate this config on every controller for every action. Also, this check may be susceptible to changing, so i'd like to update it in just one place.

How am i best to go about this? Should i be creating some sort of helper class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You want to separate that responsibility as much as you can based on your needs, or the levels of separation already established in your application. At a minimum, I would create one class that accesses the DB, and another that contains the logic to make the "if" decision. For instance Controller -> calls Helper -> calls DBAccessor

Comment: I was under the (obviously wrong) impression that you can only access the database from a controller class? I'm using Entity Framework, so is 'Helper' the correct terminology, so i can google and see if there are any tutorials on this sort of thing?

Comment: I would do a little reading into N-Tier Architecture to understand the theory behind it. For your specific needs right now, keeping it simple and using the "Helper" or "Utility" terminology are probably fine.

Comment: Also, it is perfectly acceptable to access the database outside of controllers. Some people prefer to only access the database from an entirely different project than the Web Application project, for example.

Comment: This post explains it better: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135724/separating-data-access-in-asp-net-mvc